# Expressing identifying and non-identifying relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key, identifying-relationship

**Context**

I'm learning about identifying and non-identifying relationships, and I'm wondering how I'd express them in MySQL. For practice, I've been working on a database for Pokemon. For context, every few years a new version of the game comes out and updates a lot of things, e.g. the a certain `move` that a Pokemon can use may get stronger. This update is called `generation`. Moreover, each `move` has an elemental `type`, like fire or water.

So my three entities are `move`, `generation`, and `type`. Since I want to keep track of how a Pokemon move chances over time, a `move` is in an *identifying* relationship with `generation`. The name of the move is not enough to identify it, since, e.g. the move "Karate Chop" is different in `generation` 1 than in `generation` 2. So the corresponding primary key in `generation`, `genID`, should be part of my primary key for `move`.

On the other hand, I want to store `type` as a foreign key in `move`, but I believe this is a *non-identifying* relationship. Every `move` has a `type`, so I believe it's what's called a *mandatory* non-identifying relationship.

**My attempt**

So how would I write this in MySQL? I think it would be something like

```
CREATE TABLE move (
  moveID int NOT NULL,
  genID int NOT NULL,
  typeID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (MoveID, GenID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_GenMove FOREIGN KEY (genID) REFERENCES generation(genID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_TypeMove FOREIGN KEY (typeID) REFERENCES type(typeID)
);
```

However, I couldn't find an example where a foreign key was part of the primary key in the MySQL book I'm using (they discuss identifying relationships, but I couldn't find an example with syntax). Specifically, I'm unsure whether the order I list the constraints matters (should I declare my primary keys first, then my foreign keys?)

**Indices**

Also, I believe that my composite primary key will automatically become a clustered index for my table. A common query one would do is filtering `move` by `generation`/`genID`. So this should automatically be efficient since I have an index on `genID`, even though its part of a composite key, right? Or do I need to make a separate index for `genID` alone?

Comment: *Updated:* Your attempt is correct.

Comment: The order of the constraints with respect to each other is immaterial, to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I realized the next day is that the order in which I declare my primary key matters. `(moveID, genID)` will sort by `moveID` first, then `genID`, whereas `(genID, moveID)` would sort the other way. Since I mentioned that I wanted the behavior of the latter case in my original post (picking out all `move`'s in a given `generation`), as opposed to the former case, I felt that I should point out.

Comment: You need a certain amount of reputation to be able to upvote a comment. Glad you could find your answer!

Comment: Looks like the threshold is below 19, so now I can upvote comments!

Comment: That's correct. The order of the columns within a constraint or index matters.  But the order of the constraints/indexes with respect to each other does not.